# How to change the distance from the top margin and chapter title?

Tags: margins, geometry

How decrease the distance from the top margin and chapter title only of the title page, keeping the margins of the following pages unchanged. Also, how to narrow the distance between the title of the section and the title of the chapter?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}%Sonny %Conny %Lenny %Glenn %Renje %Bjarne %Bjornstrup
\usepackage{geometry, calc, color, setspace}%
\geometry{a4paper, headsep=1.0cm, footskip=1cm, lmargin=3cm, rmargin=2cm, tmargin=3cm, bmargin=2cm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Characters}

\section{teste}
\lipsum \lipsum 
\end{document}
```

I've already looked at a lot of questions and all the answers change not only the first page, but all of the following, as well as changing the format of my title!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this. You set the `tmargin` value to where you want your chapter title placed and then use the `\topskip` to set where the rest of the text will start.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}%Sonny %Conny %Lenny %Glenn %Renje %Bjarne %Bjornstrup
\usepackage{geometry, calc, color, setspace}%

\geometry{a4paper, headsep=1.0cm, footskip=1cm, lmargin=3cm, rmargin=2cm, tmargin=1cm, bmargin=2cm}
\setlength\topskip{2cm}
\newcommand\newchapter[1]{\setlength\topskip{0cm}\chapter{#1}\setlength\topskip{2cm}}

\begin{document}
\setlength\topskip{0cm}\tableofcontents\setlength\topskip{2cm}
\newchapter{Characters}
\section{teste}
\lipsum \lipsum 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is necessary to change TeX lengths instead of just using the geometry package? Some people would consider it bad style.

Comment: @TeXnician `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry` does not work in this case.

Comment: Sorry @Georg, I corrected the question! I want to decrease the distance!

Comment: Hi, @TeXnician, i want to decrease only a little distance!

Comment: @fsbmat I changed it.

Comment: Great @Georg, thank very much! But if add \tableofcontents after of \begin{document} don't compile?

Comment: @Georg my log error: https://cdn.rawgit.com/fsbmat/StackOverflow/master/title.log

Comment: @fsbmat Ok the `\tableofcontents` command does not like when the chapter command is changed. So I updated the solution to work but it is not pretty.

Comment: @Georg True! I'm writing my thesis, that way i can not use it! But I really appreciate your help!

Comment: While this works for the output, In my editor (TexStudio) this solution breaks the auto-populated structure displayed (chapters can no longer be detected), which complicates writing.